# How create dynamically function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create some functions dynamically with javascript. all function do special work, but with different data(for example, `console.log("data")`).

```
config = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
returned = {};
for(var i in config){
    returned[config[i]] = function(){console.log(config[i])};
}
```

I above code, All functions must log a data, but different data. I want to when I call `returned["data1"]()` it log `data1`, But when I call `returned["data1"]()` it log `data3`.

Is it possible? How can I do?

Comment: All of data are string.

Comment: This is because objects are reference typed variable and it will hod reference of last value. You will have to bind each function with specific value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
returned = {};
config.forEach(function(data){
    returned[data] = function(){
       console.log(data);
    };
});
```

**Edit**

You could also extract that inner function so it's slightly more memory efficient:

```
config = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
returned = {};

function doSpecialWork(data){
    console.log(data);
};

config.forEach(function(data){
    returned[data] = doSpecialWork(data);
});
```

**Edit 2**

You could also get silly, but call yourself functional:

```
config = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];

function doSpecialWork(data){
    console.log(data);
};

returned = config.reduce(function(returned, data){
    returned[data] = doSpecialWork(data);

    return returned;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you are looking for.

```
var returned = {};
['data1', 'data2', 'data3'].forEach(function(element) { 
  returned[element] = function() { console.log(element); };
});
```

Comment: 27 sec difference...

Comment: Haha, sorry dude! Great minds though.